# Como faço para pegar o CSS correto no DOMPDF?

Tags: php, css3, codeigniter, dompdf

Bom dia Pessoal, tudo bem?

Tenho 3 arquivos: certificado.png | style.css | certificate.html

Tenho um metodo que uni eles e imprmir em PDF o certificado, quando printo na tela com var_dump sai certinho, quando gerar o pdf deixa a primeira folha em branco, segunda metade da imagem e a terceira com as descrições, e ao invés de imprimir em paisagem que está setado, ele imprimi em retrato, o que pode ser? tem algum esquema para o DOMPDF pegar o css correto?

segue metodo que junta os arquivos e faz a chamada da criação do pdf

```
  public function generateCertificate(){
        $this->load->library('CertificatePDF');
        $certificantePDF = new CertificatePDF();
        $html = file_get_contents('assets/components/certificate/certificate.html');

        $keys = array('[[SITE_URL]]');
        $values = array(site_url('assets/components/certificate'));

        $html = str_replace($keys, $values, $html);

        $filename = "certificado" . date('YmdHis');
        $dir = 'assets/download/certificados/';
        $download = true;
        $certificantePDF->createPdfFromHtml($html, $filename, $dir, $download);

        var_dump($html);
    }
```

Metodo que gera o PDF

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

require_once(__DIR__ . "/../../assets/components/dompdf/autoload.inc.php");

class CertificatePDF {

    public function createPdfFromHtml($html, $filename, $dir, $download = false) {
        $option = new Options();
        $option->set(array(
            'isPhpEnabled' => true,
            'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
            'isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true
        ));
        $dompdf = new Dompdf($option);
        $dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'landscape');
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->set_base_path(__DIR__ . "/../../");

        $dompdf->render();
        if ($download) {
            $dompdf->stream($filename . ".pdf");
        }
        file_put_contents($dir . $filename . ".pdf", $dompdf->output());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente aplicar o landscape pelo css assim:

```
@media print{@page {size: landscape}}
```